# Difficulties rendering 3D avatar with react-three-fiber and React

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm trying to render a 3D avatar using react-three-fiber and React, but I'm experiencing some difficulties with positioning the avatar. As you can see from from the following CodeSandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-ardinghelli-ypwjsb?file=/pages/index.js, the top of the avatar's head is not visible when you first render the page. However, if you change the position of the model (e.g. from [0.025, -0.9, 1] to [0.025, -1, 1]) and re-render the page, suddenly the avatar is showing correctly. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reposting the solution I got from a Reddit user:

---

it looks like the keyframe track actions["Armature|mixamo.com|Layer0"].play() pushes the model up and down.

i reexported the model
`npx gltfjsx model.glb --keepnames`
https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-lewin-rnq66m?file=/pages/index.js and that seems to do it. it should preserve names by default when animations are present, i don't get why it's omitting them. but either way, it works.

should be fixed upstream (gltfjsx) as well now. another export should include names

---